# Getting Array out of bound exception in my code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

The code below throws an *Array out of bound* exception. I want to print the blank value also.

Here `sourceDir[i].length=3` and `targetDir[i].length=10`. If I remove `sourceDir[i].getName` then it works fine.

```
int compareSize = sourceDir.length > targetDir.length ? sourceDir.length : targetDir.length;
    String[] resultArr = null;
    String resultFilename = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < compareSize; i++){
        resultFilename = currDir + "\\Results\\Result" + (i+1) + ".htm";
        readReport = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(resultFilename));
        resultArr = getResult(readReport);

        bw.write("<tr><td>" + (i+1) +  "</td><td>" + sourceDir[i].getName() + "</td><td>" 
                + targetDir[i].getName() + "</td><td>" + resultArr[0] + "</td><td>" + resultArr[1] 
                + "</td><td>" + "<a href=\"Result" + (i+1) + ".htm\">Link to Result</a></td></tr>");
    }

    bw.write("</tr></table></Div></Body></html>");
    bw.close();
}
```

Comment: try `sourceDir.length < targetDir.length` instead

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro. Obviously, setting `compareSize` to the **larger** of the two lengths will cause trouble in the loop as you have nothing preventing trying to access the array entries beyond the end of the shorter array.

Comment: I tried ...still i am getting ...if i remove sourceDir[i].getName() ..thenits working or else showing arrayindexoutofbound exception.....because sourceDir lenght is 3....and i am using loop for 10...so how to avoid that exception

Comment: where's the exception? can you put it here

Comment: any approaches will be helpful how to avoid it

Comment: Don't try and access an element of an array that is bigger than the size of the array.  If you make the change described by @cyberz, that will fix it.

Comment: can any body give some idea ....what need to do ...I mean is there any way to fix it ...I understand the problem ....like because of array size its throwing exception...what i want is ...i need different approaches .As I m new to  java so getting difficulties.

Comment: Why are you ignoring the comments that tell you how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is straight forward.

1. Consider sourceDir.length=5 and targetDir.length=3.
2. In this case compareSize=5
3. Now you are running a for loop from i=0 to 4.
4. When i=3,  sourceDir[3].getName() works fine, but targetDir[3].getName() will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException since targertDir[3] does not exist!

You will get the same ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for sourceDir[i].getName() if targetDir.length>sourceDir.length

Answer (score 0):

Ok compareSize will equal the larger number length. Your problem is in your loop one of your dir is smaller so when [i] reaches a number higher then the length of the smaller dir it will go out of bounds.

One solution is change resultArr to:

```
List<String> resultArr = new ArrayList<>();
```

And inside the for loop (makes sure nothing goes out of bounds):

```
 if(i < sourceDir.length){
        System.out.println(sourceDir[i]);   //just so you can see value
        resultArr.add(sourceDir.get(i));    //add everything to an arrayList
    }
 if(i < targetDir.length){
        System.out.println(targetDir[i]);   //just so you can see value
        resultArr.add(targetDir.get(i))     //add everything to an arrayList

    }
```

outside of 1st for loop you can iterate through the resultArr arrayList now:

```
  for(int j =0; j < resultArr.size(); j++){
         //do the code you done before from first for loop in here   
  }
```

You could use a for each loop as well but if your new to java then you're understanding of objects is probably non existent